# Parse js - unable to receive user fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I've this problem: I've seen that in Parse JS documentation, to retrieve a field from a Parse Object or a Parse User, I have to do this, for example: `var name = currentUser.get('first_name');`. I'm using it on Express.js, the problem is that it works only if, for example, `first_name` was just set in the past. If the field is empty, it doesn't retrieve anything and lock my Express app. To retrieve this user, I've made simple request:

```
   request({

      uri:'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse/users/me',
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'myAppId',
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': req.session.token
      },
      json:true    

     }).then((userData) => {

       if(userData){            
          user = Parse.Object.fromJSON(userData);
          resolve(user);

       }

    }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
```

and it works very well...so why does it not work? I need also to put masterKey in the `request`? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the problem is due to other fields, like this:

```
var otherJSObject = user.get('value').id;
```

in this case you need to see if the value exists:

```
var otherJSObject = user.get('value');

if(otherJSObject)
{
 let id = otherJSObject.id;
}
```